# Dialekt Identifizierung

Tags: dialect

Ich möchte gern wissen, welchen Dialekt im folgenden Video von den zwei jungen Damen (z.B. die Theresa) gesprochen wird. Ich weiß, dass er aus irgendwo in Österreich stammen soll..

Es ist mir wohl bewusst dass es Tirol im Titel steht. Die Damen hätten aber vielleicht her aus einer anderen Region kommen können.

https://youtu.be/33TTxbHyrqg?t=17

Comment: **Close und Down Voters:** nach heutigem Stand hatten wir beschlossen, dass wir eine Dialekt-Identifizierung zulassen wollen. Diese Frage wäre demnach *on topic*, bis wir auf Meta das Gegenteil beschließen. Siehe: https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1154/ist-es-in-ordnung-danach-zu-fragen-welche-mundart-ein-bestimmter-text-ist. "Too broad" passt jedenfalls gar nicht, denn es kann nur eine richtige Antwort geben.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ein [südbairischer](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bairische_Dialekte#S%C3%BCdbairisch) Dialekt, vermutlich Tirolerisch. Merkmale:

- Gruß: *Griaß enk!*
- *k* als *kch* gesprochen: *kchennenzulernen, Kchühe*
- *s* vor *t* als *sch* gesprochen: *Hausmannskoscht*
- *aui* für *hinauf*: *wo die Bauern s'Viech aui tan haben*
- *sein* für *sind*: *Wo sein meine Grenzen?*, *wenn viel Leut da sein*
- Negation *nit*: *Da gibts nit alles.*

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ [ja hat er](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bairische_Dialekte). Nicht schlimm, denn es passiert immer wieder dass Leute bairisch mit bay(e)risch verwechseln

Comment: @Takkat Da muss ich als "Südbayer" aber heftig widersprechen. Diese _"Identifikations Merkmale"_ haben mit unserem Dialekt rein gar nichts zu tun.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Bitte lies erst den in der Antwort verlinkten, ausführlichen und schönen Wikipedia Artikel, bevor Du hier weitere Kommentare schreibst.

Comment: @Takkat Das irgendwas auf Wikipedia geschrieben steht, hat nicht notwendigerweise etwas mit "Richtigkeit"oder "Realittsanspruch" zu tun.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ dort ist eine Reihe Primärliteratur verlinkt. Oder ziehe ein gutes gedrucktes Konversationslexikon zu Rate. Ich empfehle auch *[U.Ammon: Die deutsche Sprache in Deutschland, Österreich und der Schweiz](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=9783110147537&i=stripbooks&linkCode=qs)*, falls echtes Interesse besteht.